# Unable to settext on javafx text at runtime

Tags: javafx, textfield

I am trying to settext on a textfield after it as been opened from login window but the changes are not displaying. Please I am new to java and javafx. Below is the code which opens the new window:

```
try {
        Statement stmnt= conn.createStatement();
        rs=stmnt.executeQuery(sql);
        if(rs.next()==true){
                
            String name = null;
            Image img = null;
            
            
                 name = rs.getString("name");
                 img = new Image(rs.getBinaryStream("photo"));
                 System.out.println(name);
                
                
                Stage primaryStage = new Stage();
                
                /*FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
                
                Pane root = loader.load(getClass().getResource("main.fxml").openStream());
                mainController mnctrl = (mainController) loader.getController();
                mnctrl.dispOpInfo(name, img);*/
                
                FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("main.fxml"));     

                Parent root = (Parent)fxmlLoader.load();          
                mainController controller = fxmlLoader.<mainController>getController();
                controller.dispOpInfo(name, img);
                
                primaryStage.show(); 
                
                Scene scene = new Scene(root);
                scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
                primaryStage.setScene(scene);
                primaryStage.setTitle("BECE 2017 Validation");;
                primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("icon.png")));
                primaryStage.show();
                //
                
        }
```

and below is the code for the newly open window of it textfield is not changing at runtime

```
 @FXML TextField txtSchName = new TextField();
    
    public void populateCanInfo (String canSchool, String canName, String canState,String canGender, Image canPhoto){
            System.out.println(canGender );
            txtCanName.setText(canName);
            txtSchName.setText(canSchool);
            imgViewCan.setImage(canPhoto);
            
        //  int index=cmbCanState.getValue().indexOf(canState);
        //  cmbCanState.getSelectionModel().select(index);
            
            if(canGender.equalsIgnoreCase(canGender)){
                rbtMale.setSelected(true);
            }else{
                rbtFemale.setSelected(true);
            }
            
        }
```

Comment: Here: `@FXML TextField txtSchName = new TextField();` you are re-creating the `TextField` that was created by the `FXMLLoader`, so the `TextField` pointed by `txtSchName` is not the same you see on the GUI. Therefore, remove the `= new TextField()` part.

Comment: Thank you sir its now fixed